# Determine if Request is Legit in HttpHandler

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, httphandler

I recently set up an httpHandler to protect my HTML files from being pulled directly by nefarious users. I had never done anything like this before, and after doing a lot of research, using an httpHandler seemed to be the best result. All the tutorials, however, explained how to set up the handler but then all seemed to end with something like "Now just check to see if the request is legitimate or not!" without explaining how this might be done.

There are plenty of examples of how to stop requests coming from other domains, for example, to stop image leeching. What I want to do is allow requests for HTML files that are made by my Angular layer, but block requests made directly by the browser. That is, if Angular requests an HTML template, it should get it, but if somebody types "mysite.com/static/templates/template.html" into the browser bar, it should be blocked.

The solution I've come up with is to have Angular send a custom header with every request; the httpHandler then looks for the presence of this header and returns the HTML file if the header is present. Thus if the request doesn't come from within the Angular ecosystem, it doesn't have the header, and gets bounced. There are two problems with this method:

1. It's a bit fragile. We've had (admittedly rare) reports from users getting blocked when they shouldn't, and I haven't been able to pin down why this happens.
2. It wouldn't work for, say, javaScript files. JS files don't get loaded in the same way, so I can't protect them in the same way.

Is there a better method for telling whether a request came directly from the browser bar, or legitimately from my UI?

Front end is angular, back end is .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. The best you can do is look at headers. It's trivial for a "nefarious" user to replicate whatever a legitimate header looks like and get the data anyways.

If you think about what's going, there is no technical difference between typing in a url, the browser downloading a resource, or an ajax call(except for the headers). Even if you're using https this can easily be replicated with tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or by two to three lines of code in most modern languages.

I don't know why you're doing this, but if it's due to bandwidth or something, I'd recommend caching. It's way to detailed of a topic to go into here so I won't.

If what you're after is security of your files(for example you don't want someone looking at the js file or html file besides the browser) then you're basically out of luck, because such a thing isn't even possible.